# What transitions and triggers should be used in Unity Visual Scripting for an Animator with two main states that toggle back and forth?

Tags: unity, animator

I'm using Unity Visual Scripting and have a GameObject with a Sprite Renderer and also an Animator component with 3 states: FadeIn, Fadeout and Idle.

The main goal is to control the alpha transparency of the Sprite Renderer:

- The GameObject starts off with an alpha transparency of 0.
- The Fadein state uses an animation clip to bring the alpha transparency of the Sprite Renderer from 0 to 1.
- The FadeOut state uses another animation clip to bring to the alpha transparency from 1 to 0.

Here is the animation state machine:

[image]

The Transition from Idle to Fade In uses a Trigger parameter called startFadeIn.  It runs the Fade In animation clip, and appears to works perfectly.

In the code, after the startFadeIn trigger is called then a Boolean parameter "FadeInComplete" is set to true.  That triggers the Transition from Fade In back to Idle, which has no animation clip.

So far, so good.  However, once the Animation State is in Idle... the alpha transparency continuously resets to zero, causing the entire Sprite to disappear.  I say continuously because when I use the Inspector to manually set the alpha transparency to any other value (e.g. 1), it immediately gets reset to 0 again.

I can't figure out why that is happening.  When the animation state machine is in the Idle state, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?  My main goal is to be able to issue triggers to toggle this Animation State machine between the Fade In and Fade Out states.  I added the Idle state to help with that, but I'm perfectly happy  to structure this another way!

Comment: Maybe this behavior is related to [the WriteDefaults setting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/196915/what-does-write-defaults-in-the-animation-state-inspector-actually-do) on your animation states.

Comment: @Philipp Thank you so much, you saved me after several days of struggle!  If you wouldn't mind putting this as an answer, I would love to accept it!!

Comment: One thing that I still don't get yet: if values are "reset back to the default upon entering this state" if WriteDefaults is on, then why couldn't I manually reset the values in the Inspector?

Comment: I will mark this question as a duplicate, then.

Comment: I will ask about the manual resetting of values in a separate question then.

Comment: After a lot of research, finally found out why I couldn't manually reset the values in the Inspector: https://forum.unity.com/threads/animator-locking-animated-value-even-when-current-state-has-no-curves-keys-for-that-value.440363/

Comment: Can this question be re-opened?  I've learned more since posting it, and would like to write a complete answer.