# LocalPosition always (0, 0, 0) on UI component after assigning it in script

Tags: unity, c#, gui, transformation, card-game

I have a card prefab setup to render a card like this:

[image: card prefab]

I'm in the process of creating a hand prefab to contain a set of cards and manage the animation to slide in each of the cards. Each hand has 5 cards, stacked vertically, with the intention that each will overlap the last with a little vertical spacing.

[image: desired outcome]

To do this dynamically within the game, the hand has a script component that takes all 5 cards (as data objects) and attempts to instantiate the card prefab and position it to achieve the desired outcome. It also attempts to reach this point by animating the cards by sliding them in. Unfortunately, I end up with 5 cards stacked on top of each other, with their `transform.localPosition` set to `(0, 0, 0)`.

[image: actual outcome]

```
private IEnumerator ArrangeCards()
{
    var currentPoint = startPoint;
    var initialPoint = new Vector2(0f, -700f);

    foreach (var card in cards)
    {
        // TODO: Play sound effect of card sliding in.

        var gameObject = Instantiate(gameCardPrefab);
        gameObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
        gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, 0f);

        var gameCard = gameObject.GetComponent<GameCard>();
        gameCard.Initialize(card, isPlayerHand, showCardFaces);

        gameCards.Add(gameCard);

        // var cardTransform = gameCard.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        // cardTransform.position = initialPoint;

        // yield return MoveCardToTargetPoint(cardTransform, currentPoint);
        yield return null;

        currentPoint.y -= verticalSpace;
    }
}
```

> See [here](https://pastebin.com/3EMXbnJ4) for the full script component.

Below are the objects and components in the hierarchy.

### Scene hierarchy

[image: scene hierarchy]

### UI Canvas

[image: UI canvas]

### Card Hand

[image: card hand]

### Card Prefab

[image: card prefab]

It appears that the `Animator` component attached to the `Card` prefab (object when instantiated) is causing the issue. The animator is used to "flip" the card, so it affects the position as well as whether the front or back of the card is active. This animator is blocking changes to both the active state of the front and back objects, as well as the position of the card itself.

I have tried disabling the **Write Defaults**, as suggested in the comments. To further illustrate this scenario, I've created a [minimal reproduction](https://github.com/sladesamuel/unity-animator-resetting-position) of the issue. Please view the README in the GitHub repository for an explanation and demonstration of the issue.

I'm unsure as to why the animator is affecting the position change in this way.

Comment: `LocalPosition` is used when placing things in 3D space in the scene view. UI elements tend to use properties of type [RectTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html) for UI placement.

Comment: Even easier is if you use the grid position component. No need to specify the position directly, just the spacing is needed and the component does the rest https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html

Comment: What components do you have on the parent object these are being spawned under?

Comment: @Basic I've tried using `RectTransform`, but the effect is the same (the position is slightly more to the left, but all stacked again). I always assumed `RectTransform` replaced the `Transform` property (purely since it's not available on the editor), but I'm guessing this isn't entirely accurate?

@Zibelas thanks, I'll take a look into that. I did try to use a `VerticalLayoutGroup` but I wanted more control over the position.

@DMGregory I've editing the question with this info

Comment: You may be interested in this [previous Q&A relating to configuring animations to overwrite or ignore properties that they don't animate](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/196915/39518). In future, make sure to either eliminate possible confounding causes like animations when making a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example to post here, or ensure your initial post mentions their presence. Don't segregate edits under "Edit / Edit 2" headings — edit history is already tracked automatically, so just edit the post so it reads as though it had included all that info from the beginning.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for the link - I’ll have a read through to understand the explanation. I was unaware that animators could have caused this behaviour as I’ve not experienced it before, which is why I didn’t mention it in the question initially. Also, with the edits, this is the same approach many others have taken for years in an attempt to make it clear which part is new without digging through the history. The use of this approach versus not is likely preference

Comment: That's why we ask folks to build a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example when posting a troubleshooting question here — to eliminate & isolate both the confounding factors you're aware of and the ones you're not aware of. By removing everything not provably needed to reproduce the problem, you discover what's actually relevant (and might even solve the problem yourself in the process!) Regarding "many have done it for years", yes, there are a lot of bad habits on this site we're trying to curb. Long chains of updates over concisely-stated questions is one of them.

Comment: @DMGregory I have created a minimal reproduction of this issue and rewrote part of the question as per your suggestions, linking to this reproduction. Hopefully, this helps to better illustrate the issue. I am confident my issue is related to not understanding how the animator works / affects properties. So hopefully this will lead to being pointed in the right direction to gain this understanding